Are there free CSAM hash API?
I have a website in which people can upload all kinds of images and videos. I want to add a protection layer against uploading CSAM (Child sexual abuse materials) by comparing the hash of the file content before allowing it to be uploaded. I'm searching for such databases but the ones I found actually are only shared among law enforcement agencies. I would like to use something simple as where I just upload a hash (sha256sum for example) to the API and the API returns me if this hash exists in its database or not so I can block the content before it gets uploaded to my site. Does a service like that exists for free?
